# Retrieving images in ImageView through JSON

Tags: java, android, json, android-layout, android-activity

I have created an activity that populates list of arrays through JSON data, and where when a user clicks on an array of items, a new activity is shown displaying information pertaining to that item. With help, I have only managed to display strings on that page.

In other words, in my single item click I am able to retrieve strings, which is ironic since I am able to populate images through JSON in the list of arrays.

In the layout for the single item activity, I have created a horizontal slide gallery that holds 4 pictures, but would like each of these images to be populated through JSON data.

Below is activity code that populates a list of arrays and make references to the single item click activity

```
   public class CasualEventsActivity extends Activity {

        private static final String URL_WEB_SERVICE = "xxxxx";
        private GridView gv;
        private ArrayList<Events_List> container;
        private ArrayList<Events_List> items;
        public Uri list_item_bac;
        public String list_item_name;
        public String list_item_description;
        public String list_item_location;
        public String single_list_item_description;
        public String list_item_price;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.events_list_layout);
            gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
            container = new ArrayList<Events_List>();
            //download JSON
            listDownload();


            GridView s = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
            s.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(CasualEventsActivity.this,CasualEventsSingleItemActivity.class);

                    intent.putExtra("list_item_name", container.get(position).getList_item_title());
                    intent.putExtra("list_item_location", container.get(position).getList_item_location());
                    intent.putExtra("single_list_item_description", container.get(position).getSingle_list_item_description());
                    startActivity(intent); //start Activity
                }
            });
        }
        public void listDownload(){
            RequestQueue volley = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            JsonObjectRequest json = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET, URL_WEB_SERVICE, null, ResponseListener(), ErrorListener());
            volley.add(json);
        }

        private Response.Listener<JSONObject> ResponseListener() {
            return new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        //your JSON Array
                        JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray("list_item");
                        for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
                            container.add(convertirAnuncio(array.getJSONObject(i)));
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    gv.setAdapter(new AdapterEvents(getApplicationContext(),container));
                    }
                };
            };


        private Response.ErrorListener ErrorListener() {
            return new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) { }
            };
        }

        //object JSON
        private final Events_List convertirAnuncio(JSONObject obj) throws JSONException {
            long id = obj.getLong("id"); //id 
            String list_item_name = obj.getString("list_item_name"); 
            String list_item_location = obj.getString("list_item_location"); 
            String list_item_description = obj.getString("list_item_description");
            String single_list_item_description = obj.getString("single_list_item_description");
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(obj.getString("list_item_bac"));
            return new Events_List(id, list_item_location, single_list_item_description,list_item_name,list_item_description,list_item_price, uri);
        }
    }
```

Single item Activity

```
public class CasualEventsSingleItemActivity extends Activity {

    // Declare Variables
    String list_item_name;
    String list_item_description;
    String list_item_price;
    String list_item_location;

    String single_list_item_description;




    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_events_single_item);





        Intent i = getIntent();
        list_item_name = i.getStringExtra("list_item_name");
        list_item_location = i.getStringExtra("list_item_location");

       // Uri uri = Uri.parse(obj.getString("list_item_bac"));


        single_list_item_description = i.getStringExtra("single_list_item_description");

        TextView txtname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView txtlocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.location);
        TextView txtsdescription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sdescription);


        ImageView hsvimage1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.hsvimage1);
        ImageView hsvimage2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.hsvimage2);
        ImageView hsvimage3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.hsvimage3);



        // Set results to the TextViews
        txtname.setText(list_item_name);
        txtlocation.setText(list_item_location);
        txtsdescription.setText(single_list_item_description);


        Button mConfirm2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bConfirm2);
        mConfirm2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

               // Create the class and the columns
                currentUser.saveInBackground();

                currentUser.put("ActivityName", list_item_name); 
                currentUser.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);

                        if (e == null) {
                            // Success!
                            Intent intent = new Intent(CasualEventsSingleItemActivity.this, usermatch.class);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                        else {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CasualEventsSingleItemActivity.this);
                            builder.setMessage(e.getMessage())
                                .setTitle(R.string.signup_error_title)
                                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                            dialog.show();
                        }
                   }
               });
                //CasualEventsSingleItemActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(CasualEventsSingleItemActivity.this, MatchingActivity.class));
            }
        });


    }
}
```

In particular, below is the line where I would want JSON data to be associated with the ImageView

```
 ImageView hsvimage1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.hsvimage1);
    ImageView hsvimage2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.hsvimage2);
    ImageView hsvimage3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.hsvimage3);
```

Single Item layout activity code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/blue_bac3"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:alpha="0.9"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        android:shadowColor="#000000"
        android:shadowDx="3"
        android:shadowDy="3"
        android:shadowRadius="0.01"
        android:textColor="#82CAFF"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/location"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:shadowColor="#000000"
        android:shadowDx="3"
        android:shadowDy="3"
        android:shadowRadius="0.01"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#f2f2f2"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dividertop"
        android:layout_width="370dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/location"
        android:alpha="0.6"
        android:background="@drawable/divider11"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dividerbottom"
        android:layout_width="370dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/vsvdescription"
       android:alpha="0.6"
        android:background="@drawable/divider11"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_head"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:padding="1dp" />

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/isgallery"
        android:layout_width="370dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dividerbottom"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
         >

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

               <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/hsvimage1"
                android:layout_width="148dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:padding="1dp" />
              <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/hsvimage2"
                android:layout_width="148dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:padding="1dp" />
              <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/hsvimage3"
                android:layout_width="148dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="#CCC"
                android:padding="1dp" />
              <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/hsvimage4"
                android:layout_width="148dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:padding="1dp" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                  </HorizontalScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bConfirm2"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/isgallery"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:alpha="0.7"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/gray_bac"
        android:text="Confirm"
        android:textColor="#2B3856"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

     <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/vsvdescription"
        android:layout_width="370dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp" 
        android:padding="5dp"       

        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dividertop"
         >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sdescription"
        android:layout_width="370dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:alpha="0.65"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The activity class that manages the JSON strings

```
public class Events_List {
public long id;
public String list_item_title;
public String list_item_location;
public String list_item_price;
public Uri single_list_item_bac;
public String list_item_description;
public String single_list_item_description;

public Uri url;

public Events_List(long id, String list_item_location, String single_list_item_description, String list_item_title, String list_item_description, String list_item_price, Uri url){
    this.id = id;
    this.list_item_title = list_item_title;
    this.list_item_location = list_item_location;
    this.list_item_description = list_item_description;
    this.single_list_item_description = single_list_item_description;
    this.list_item_price = list_item_price;
    this.url = url;
}

public String getList_item_title()
{
    return this.list_item_title;
}

public String getList_item_location()
{
    return this.list_item_location;
}

public String getList_item_price()
{
    return this.list_item_price;
}

public String getList_item_description()
{
    return this.list_item_description;
}

public String getSingle_list_item_description()
{
    return this.single_list_item_description;
}


}
```

If you need further clarification, let me know.
Thanks in advance

**Update**

```
public class CasualEventsSingleItemActivity extends Activity {

    // Declare Variables
    String list_item_name;
    String list_item_description;
    String list_item_price;
    String list_item_location;

    String single_list_item_description;




    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_events_single_item);


        RequestQueue mRequestQueue = null;
        ImageLoader mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue,
                new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
            private final LruCache<String, Bitmap>
                    cache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(20);

            @Override
            public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
                return cache.get(url);
            }

            @Override
            public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
                cache.put(url, bitmap);
            }
        });


        Intent i = getIntent();
        list_item_name = i.getStringExtra("list_item_name");
        list_item_location = i.getStringExtra("list_item_location");



        single_list_item_description = i.getStringExtra("single_list_item_description");

        TextView txtname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView txtlocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.location);
        TextView txtsdescription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sdescription);


        NetworkImageView hsvimage1 = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.hsvimage1);
        NetworkImageView hsvimage2 = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.hsvimage2);
        NetworkImageView hsvimage3 = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.hsvimage3);

        // Get image URLs from your previous network request...
        // I could not determine where this is stored from code in your question.
        String url1 = "list_item_bac";   // e.g. http://example.com/images/image1.png
        String url2 = "list_item_bac";
        String url3 = "list_item_bac";

        // Set the URL of the image that should be loaded into this view, and
        // specify the ImageLoader that will be used to make the request.
        hsvimage1.setImageUrl(url1, mImageLoader);
        hsvimage2.setImageUrl(url2, mImageLoader);
        hsvimage3.setImageUrl(url3, mImageLoader);


        // Set results to the TextViews
        txtname.setText(list_item_name);
        txtlocation.setText(list_item_location);
        txtsdescription.setText(single_list_item_description);


        Button mConfirm2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bConfirm2);
        mConfirm2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

               // Create the class and the columns
                currentUser.saveInBackground();

                currentUser.put("ActivityName", list_item_name); 
                currentUser.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);

                        if (e == null) {
                            // Success!
                            Intent intent = new Intent(CasualEventsSingleItemActivity.this, usermatch.class);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                        else {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CasualEventsSingleItemActivity.this);
                            builder.setMessage(e.getMessage())
                                .setTitle(R.string.signup_error_title)
                                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                            dialog.show();
                        }
                   }
               });
                //CasualEventsSingleItemActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(CasualEventsSingleItemActivity.this, MatchingActivity.class));
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: ¿How does the image is represented in the JSON?

Comment: The image is referred to as a string. For instance, "list_item_image1" => "image.jpg",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use Volley's [NetworkImageView](http://afzaln.com/volley/com/android/volley/toolbox/NetworkImageView.html) and [ImageLoader](http://afzaln.com/volley/com/android/volley/toolbox/ImageLoader.html) which will do all of the hard work for you in the background.

First, change all of you ImageViews to NetworkImageViews:

```java
           <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
            android:id="@+id/hsvimage1"
            ... />
          <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
            android:id="@+id/hsvimage2"
            ... />
          <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
            android:id="@+id/hsvimage3"
            ... />
```

Next, create an ImageLoader. You will most likely want to create an singleton to hold this:

```java
    mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(Volley.newRequestQueue(this),
            new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
        private final LruCache<String, Bitmap>
                cache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(20);

        @Override
        public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
            return cache.get(url);
        }

        @Override
        public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
            cache.put(url, bitmap);
        }
    });
```

Then all there is left to do is set the URL for each NetworkImageView.

```java
NetworkImageView hsvimage1 = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.hsvimage1);
NetworkImageView hsvimage2 = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.hsvimage2);
NetworkImageView hsvimage3 = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.hsvimage3);

// Get image URLs from your previous network request...
// I could not determine where this is stored from code in your question.
String url1 = ...;   // e.g. http://example.com/images/image1.png
String url2 = ...;
String url3 = ...;

// Set the URL of the image that should be loaded into this view, and
// specify the ImageLoader that will be used to make the request.
hsvimage1.setImageUrl(url1, mImageLoader);
hsvimage2.setImageUrl(url2, mImageLoader);
hsvimage3.setImageUrl(url3, mImageLoader);
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. I made a few changes due to error such as hsvimage1.setUrl(url1, mImageLoader); changed to  hsvimage1.setImageUrl(url1, mImageLoader); as well as I had to initialized mRequestQueue, though I think it being equal to null is false. As for the string url, I replaced the ... with the JSON string. In the sense that in the JSON data there's a line that refers to an image url such as "list_item_bac"=> "image.com/image.jpg". I have updated layout as suggested. I have added the updated code under the update section of my initial post.
Thanks

Comment: I have fixed the error you mentioned and used Volley.newRequestQueue(this) as the RequestQueue like you did in CasualEventsActivity. Hope that works.

Comment: Thank you. Your help has greatly resolved my first problem, which is displaying image in the activity, my second issue resolves around displaying the images through JSON data, where instead of having String url3 = "image.com/image.png", I would have String url3 = "list_image1 ";, where list_image1 refers to a JSON string that links to an image url, and where the JSON link can be found at for example website.com/json.php